# Code Composer Studio - MSP430 Compile Error "recipe for target failed"

Tags: makefile, compilation, msp430

I am attempting to use the MSP430 Launchpad and Code Composer Studio again after some 4 years. I previously had CCS v5 installed and recently installed v7 into the D Drive (my own choice)

After running into a compile error for the last few hours that I haven't been able to fix...I discovered I had v5 files still on the computer. So I uninstalled v7, manually removed all v5 files, and then reinstalled CCS v7 into the C drive (the default directory)

I get the same error still:

```
"C:\\ti\\ccsv7\\utils\\bin\\gmake" -k -j 4 all -O
subdir_rules.mk:9: recipe for target 'blink.obj' failed
gmake: *** [blink.obj] Error 1
gmake: Target 'all' not remade because of errors.
**** Build Finished ****
```

Now, the code I'm running is sample code that came with the package so I assume that it's correct. The file the error is referring to seems to be auto generated upon an attempt to compile so it seems unlikely there's anything wrong with the code in it as it's made by the folks who made the compiler/makefile I assume??

Line 9 is:

```
@echo 'Building file: $<'
```

[Code Composer Editor View - Attached Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yept.png)

I pressed enter a few times for the really long path definition in line 11, so all the includes have populated down to line 17, just for ease of showing in the image, but they are in fact all in line 11.

Answer (score 1):

OK folks, I discovered the problem. It was my Internet Security.
I looked at the Comodo Internet Security Log and it pretty much blocked all of the "make" attempts.

Just disabled Anti-Virus/Security etc. and it finally built the object file.

Need to add CCS to the approved applications list I guess.